# Declare multiple views with a similar name (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to declare and hide some views on the activity, but it's too complicated and consumes a lot of time. Can i do this with a loop or something?

```
//Startup
    //Hide msgs
    CardView msgUser1v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgUser1v);
    msgUser1v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgBot1v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgBot1v);
    msgBot1v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgUser2v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgUser2v);
    msgUser2v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgBot2v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgBot2v);
    msgBot2v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgUser3v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgUser3v);
    msgUser3v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgBot3v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgBot3v);
    msgBot3v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgUser4v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgUser4v);
    msgUser4v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgBot4v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgBot4v);
    msgBot4v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgUser5v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgUser5v);
    msgUser5v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    CardView msgBot5v = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.msgBot5v);
    msgBot5v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be a good way to do it:

```
List<CardView> cards = new ArrayList<CardView>();
for (int i = 1 ; i <= cardsCount ; i++)
{
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("msgBot"+i+"v", "id", context.getPackageName());
    cards.add((CardView) findViewById(id));
}
```

Now you have all your card views in cards array.
 If you want to make them invisible, you can do it easily like this:

```
for(CardView c : cards){
    c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: 'for(CardView c : cards){
    cards.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}'

Answer (score 0):

if your card views are under some container like relative layout, then you can iterate through the childs.

```
int childs = relativeLayout.getChildCount(); 
for(int i=0; i<childs; i++){
    View child = relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
     if(child instanceOf CardView){
             child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
}
```

you can further put more condition checks to exclude certain card views.

if `CardViews` are thr only item in your container, and you want to hide all of them, then yoi can simply set the visibility of parent layout.

`relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`